# Vectorise a function with a supplied variable

Tags: r, vectorization

I have a function I've been trying to vectorise going from `if(){}` to `ifelse()`. It works fine when all the arguments to the function are contained within the data set it is working on, but if I supply an argument as a string, then the vectorisation stops and the first result is used for the whole data set.

Here's an example

```
# data
dat <- data.frame(var1 = rep(c(0,1), 4), 
                  var2 = c(rep("a", 4), rep("b", 4))
                  )

# function
my_fun <- function(x, y){
  z <- ifelse(y == "a", fun_a(x), fun_b(x))
  return(z)
}

fun_a <- function(x){
  z <- ifelse(x == 0, "zero", x)
  return(z)
}

fun_b <- function(x){
  z <- ifelse(x == 1, "ONE", x)
  return(z)
}
dat$var3 <- my_fun(dat$var1, dat$var2)
```

This returns what I expect, a vector with a row-wise value based on var1 and var2

```
> dat
  var1 var2 var3
1    0    a zero
2    1    a    1
3    0    a zero
4    1    a    1
5    0    b    0
6    1    b  ONE
7    0    b    0
8    1    b  ONE
```

However, I want to use this functions on different data sets where var2 is not included. I realise that an easy way around would be to add var2 as an extra column in the data set, but I don't really want to do that.

This is what happens when I supply var2 as a string:

```
other_dat <- data.frame(var1 = rep(c(0,1), 4))
other_dat$var3 <- my_fun(other_dat$var1, y = "a")
other_dat
  var1 var3
1    0 zero
2    1 zero
3    0 zero
4    1 zero
5    0 zero
6    1 zero
7    0 zero
8    1 zero
```

How can I vectorise this function so that it accepts a string argument and returns the result I desire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can vectorise the y i.e. make y of similar length as x and then the ifelse will apply the function my_func on all the values.  Revised code:

```
# data
dat <- data.frame(var1 = rep(c(0,1), 4), 
                  var2 = c(rep("a", 4), rep("b", 4))
                  )

# function
my_fun <- function(x, y){
  if(length(y) == 1) {
    y <- rep(y, length(x))
  }
  z <- ifelse(y == "a", fun_a(x), fun_b(x))
  return(z)
}

fun_a <- function(x){
  z <- ifelse(x == 0, "zero", x)
  return(z)
}

fun_b <- function(x){
  z <- ifelse(x == 1, "ONE", x)
  return(z)
}
dat$var3 <- my_fun(dat$var1, "a")

other_dat <- data.frame(var1 = rep(c(0,1), 4))
other_dat$var3 <- my_fun(other_dat$var1, y = "a")
other_dat
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect, thanks very much. That's a nice solution I had overlooked.